# Do you think I was too harsh?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

It seems to be I started off nicely enough, but I really feel that OP shouldn’t be messing around with `ArrayLists` when he can’t do a simple dry-run.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31050378/what-is-wrong-with-the-code-particularly-the-add-method

Screenshot of the comments for those who don't have 10k reputation: (the question's been deleted)

[image]

[My guilty conscience awaits your opinion]

Comment: The only problem I see on your end is that you probably should have given up on this user a bit earlier.  He seems to be a lost cause, expecting nothing less than someone to do all of his work for him without him needing to understand anything about what's going on.  So while it seems you're wasting your time trying to help him, I don't see anything inappropriate/offensive/rude about any of your comments.

Comment: Thanks Servy, I feel good now :)

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "dry-run" in this context, to be honest.

Comment: @JonSkeet If he would have dry-run the code, then he would have discovered that `al` contains only one element, and hence sublist would  be out of range.

Comment: @RishavKundu: Repeating the term doesn't explain what you mean by it. Do you mean stepping through it in a debugger?

Comment: @JonSkeet Running the program on paper

Comment: @GrantWinney: If it's not a common term, then effectively castigating the OP for not knowing it is a bad idea.

Comment: @JonSkeet Then I should apologise.

Comment: I think that would be appropriate - although the overall point of "the user probably isn't up to the task they're attempting" is still valid.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for your opinion. In retrospect, rudeness never helps.

Comment: I don't think anything was wrong about it, I did not know anything about the term "dry run" but it took 1 minute to find out, if you want to find out an answer to your problem then you will look it up, it you don't look up advice people give you, then you are more than likely just looking for the answer to be given to you.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about this.  IMO your comments were not rude, and you did a decent job of warding off an impatient tone.  And you handled refusing to provide your email very well.  You were to-the-point without being rude.

Comment: @ryanyuyu my email was two mouse clicks away, if he wanted it ;)

Comment: @RishavKundu It's not obvious that you have a personal site on your profile, or that you have your e-mail address on that site, unless you've already visited it. So he couldn't be expected to know that.

Comment: @TylerH just saying that information will be provided for those who search for it.

Comment: I feel bad that @torpillo just deleted his answer when I was going to write a comment agreeing with him.

Comment: If I was in a suspicious frame of mind, I would say that the OP had copied some other student's homework before it was fully debugged and, being completely clueless re. debugging, decided to get SO contributors to do it for him.  I don't believe for a millisecond that the OP did any debugging at all.  If it was me, I would never apologise for challenging an OP for further info, either on the code or what they found out when they did their own debugging, (ie. when they did none).

Comment: @Martin even if OP has not done any debugging and has blatantly ripped it from somewhere, I shouldn’t be rude with him. Everything can be communicated nicely.

Comment: @RishavKundu - it aparrently can not, since no-debug-effort questions are continually dumped on SO with total indifference to the contributors who might wish to answer them.  If they get answered anyway, the SO Q&A repository will fill up, (more), with the between-the-lines message of 'I don't need to do any debugging, I can always con those slaves on SO to do it for me'.

Comment: @Martin you have a valid point, but there are many beginners who truly try and get stuck. It's not fair to deny them help.

Comment: Are beginners now classed as 'professional and enthusiast programmers'?

Comment: @Martin I’m sorry, I don’t understand what that comment means?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Specifically: 'Don't ask about...Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)'

Comment: Here's another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056500/infixtopostfix-code-c

Comment: @Martin Yes, but there are many who *have* tried, and have some sort of half-baked idea. IMO that they should be given help (you may not agree), which is also why I never down vote a question on face value. I know that is hard to write good questions (none of my _own_ questions have ever received upvotes). I usually write a comment clarifying things from the OP.

Comment: Martin James' comment in linked question FTW.   QOTD.

Comment: @MadConan I have to google terms like QOTD every other day I’m browsing meta lol.

Comment: If Jon Skeet didn't even know what you meant by "Dry Run" then I suggest you stop using this term within this context.

Comment: You seem frustrated here but I don't blame you. However, you did not resort to being rude, maybe the very first comment could have been a bit better, I normally only lower my tone on blatantly copy and paste questions and that seems more like a question from a noobie who didn't do their research. But overall I would say you were frustrated but not rude

Comment: FYI, "dry run" to mean working the code through on paper isn't something I've encountered in ~28 years of professional software development (or in study before that).

Comment: This is why we can't have nice things.

Answer (score 65):

I think you were borderline appropriate, tonally. You didn't attempt to insult the user or their knowledge, and you wrote *several* comments, all trying to help the user understand. However, you did come off as *immediately* exasperated with your first comment:

> Did you even *try* to solve your problem?

This typically is not a constructive thing to say. At least, it's not a constructive way to ask that. It puts the user on the defensive with thoughts like:

> Of course I've tried stuff! So much stuff that I couldn't even list it in a simple comment! How dare you?!

And that puts users at odds with each other, which goes against the whole point of the site, which is to *help other programmers*.

I think clarifying what a dry run is would be very helpful. I know what the term means outside of programming, but have never heard it used in this context before, so I too was stumped until you explained it in your comments here. An apology never goes amiss, either, though that's certainly up to you.

Comment: I have apologised to him :)

Comment: @RishavKundu Brownie points for you for doing that and for asking this question in the first place :-)

Comment: @TylerH - good point - I get so incensed by these no-effort SO questions and I forgot to upvote this one, now fixed:)

Comment: I also get a little impatience with some users, but my reason for that is that I wish I knew how to convert them from users that won't try to users that give a darn about their work/programming/profession. Sometimes I have to walk away from SO to keep myself from elevating to a more hostile tone.  I *do* think it goes a long way to apologize for perceived rudeness though, IRL as well as here.  So thank you for making this a more welcoming place.

Comment: @BlackVegetable I feel your pain on that; I'd love to have the time and other resources to convert every help vampire I see into someone who contributes back to the developer community!

Comment: +1 for clarifying what a "dry run" is. I, too, have never heard the term used to describe working out what happens mentally or on paper. Sometimes we think a term we hear or use is common, when it might be a lot less well known than we thought.

Answer (score 10):

*The question was not quality*

First off, the question itself has severe issues. It is a code dump, its title literally starts off with "what is wrong with the code"; it has poor grammar, formatting and indentation; and it makes no attempt whatsoever to describe what was supposed to happen versus what was actually happening.

*What have you tried*

I think you had good intentions, but really it was an inappropriate line to take. This is why *what have you tried* is literally banned on Stack Overflow as a comment. Back when the ban was first implemented 2 years ago the reasoning was explained by Shog9♦ as

["*If you don't have the time or inclination to engage in conversation with the author of a post, don't comment - just vote.*"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/178816)

Essentially the comment "Have you tried anything at all to debug your program?" is a workaround for a "What have you tried?" comment. If you are willing to put some time into a question then you should be aiming to end up with the result of an answerable question. If that is not possible, then there is really no point in commenting.

*What have I tried*

I have also come across these same types of questions every time I am clicking around to answer. This scenario is definitely not new, and I have even addressed what I have tried previously in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173356/178816).

> I usually ask for an edit by stating what I feel others would need to know to be able to properly answer the question, a helpful hint, a generally accepted standard or guideline, or what I feel is lacking.
>
> In my opinion, at the heart of the "what have you tried" issue is what is known as a ["help vampire"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19665/178816). It seems to me, "what have you tried" usually stems from a reluctance of users to blatantly do the work of others. This is where it is important to provide guidance on how the OP can share more details or more requirements to narrow down what is usually a rather vague question.
>
> Unfortunately, sometimes the OP really is trying to just get some very specific work done for them here without trying themselves, and in that case I feel a vote to close is appropriate.
>
> As stated in the linked material, if the question is beyond saving it can always been downvoted and closed. Ideally, it would be improved so that someone can answer it.